# How can I see the details when I mouseover on a specific box?

Tags: javascript, css

When I put mouseover on a specific box, I see the details, and when I put mouseout, I make the details disappear.

**html**

```
<nav>
      <div>
        <div class="nav-container">
          <a href="./about.html"><div class="nav-box">ABOUT</div></a>
          <a href="./publication.html"><div class="nav-box" id="publication-box">PUBLICATION</div></a>
          <a href="./members.html"><div class="nav-box">MEMBERS</div></a>
        </div>
        <div id="publication-detail">
          <div id="international-publication"><a id="desc" href="./international_pub.html">international publication</a></div>
          <div id="domestic-publication"><a id="desc" href="./domestic_pub.html">domestic publication</a></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

**css**

```
.show {
    visibility: visible;
  }

  #publication-detail {
    margin: 2px 0 0 283px;
    visibility: hidden;
  }
```

**js**

```
const publication = document.getElementById("publication-box");
const publication_detail = document.getElementById("publication-detail");
function showDetail() {
publication_detail.classList.add("show")
}
publication.addEventListener("mouseover", showDetail);
```

If I mouseover the publication box, the publication_detail adds a show class,

but I can't see the publication-detail. How should I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this

```js
const publication = document.getElementById("publication-box");
const publication_detail = document.getElementById("publication-detail");

publication.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
  publication_detail.classList.add("show")
});

publication.addEventListener("mouseout", () => {
  publication_detail.classList.remove("show")
});
```

```css
.show {
  visibility: visible !important;
}

#publication-detail {
  margin: 2px 0 0 283px;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha256-4+XzXVhsDmqanXGHaHvgh1gMQKX40OUvDEBTu8JcmNs=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <div>
    <div class="nav-container">
      <a href="./about.html">
        <div class="nav-box">ABOUT</div>
      </a>
      <a href="./publication.html">
        <div class="nav-box" id="publication-box">PUBLICATION</div>
      </a>
      <a href="./members.html">
        <div class="nav-box">MEMBERS</div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div id="publication-detail">
      <div id="international-publication"><a id="desc" href="./international_pub.html">international publication</a></div>
      <div id="domestic-publication"><a id="desc" href="./domestic_pub.html">domestic publication</a></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Is the problem caused by not using !important?

Comment: when you have visibility in two styles. one of them need to take precedent